# Android Layout Screen Size Conflicts (values-normal / values-large)

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm developing simple Android app and I have a problem with multiple screen size support. I'm going to support normal and large screens and I have 2 values resources:

- values-normal(supports between 3.5 inc to 5.0 inc)
- values-large(supports between 5.1 inc to 5.7 inc)

I've set dimensions in these resources but 5.1 inc and 5.2 inc screen sizes get values from values-large so view becomes awful they should get values from values-normal.

So, what can I do? How can I set these specific inches to get values from values-normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i set these specific inches to get values from values-normal.

You can't. However, you can [switch to the `-swNNNdp`, `-wNNNdp`, or `-hNNNdp` selectors](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html), instead of `normal` and `large`, to provide your own points to switch to new resources.

Answer (score 2):

Although the answers of CommonsWare and Rustam are correct, but I think in your case the better approach is to manage your values as :

**values-hdpi 

values-mdpi 

values-xhdpi**

you can test this dimension on different preview devices in your IDE of chioce.

Comment: is this going to solve my problem for 5.1 and 5.2 inc screen sizes?

Comment: It depends on the resoultion of the device/emulator. A 5.1 or 5.2 device is supposedly of mdpi resolution, But it can differ based on brands and models. My suggestion is to organize your values as I mentioned and test the results , using the preview panel in your IDE

Comment: To clarify: this answer makes the assumption that the OP does not actually want to pull different dimensions for different screen sizes like he said, but rather for different pixel densities.

Answer (score 1):

**Better way is to create value resource like this :**

```
values-sw480dp
values-sw600dp
values-sw800dp
values-sw1080dp
```

Comment: this is going to solve the problem ? what is the differences declare    values-normal instead of values-sw600?

Comment: @ertu.ctn sw600 is an example of a numeric selector. There are defined set of numbers describing device screen sizes, which can be used to select resources or otherwise adjust your UI. The numbers describing the device screen sizes are all in 'dp' units. This is primarily for tablets. values-normal is an example of a screen-size bucket. There are three screen-size buckets based on 'dp' units. This is what you should use for non-tablet devices. For more info, look here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html